# Why do we need to require that $0$ is in an ideal?

Tags: ring-theory

An ideal is defined like this in my text:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An ideal of $R$ is a subset $I \subset R$ satisfying the following properties:

1) $0 \in I$

2) $a - b \in I$ for all $a, b \in I$

3) for all $r \in R$ and $a \in I$, we have that $ra \in I$.

But doesn't 1) follow from 2) as $a - a = 0 \in I$ for $a \in I$? Or even 3) for that matter because $0a = 0$.

Comment: Otherwise the ideal could be empty.

Comment: @TobErnack well, that was a face palm moment for me, thank you.

Comment: You could replace condition 1) by «I is not empty», in fact.